# How do I compare dates in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date

How can I check if a date captured in the database is less than the current date?

```
foreach( $results as $r ) {
$date = $r['date'];

if($date < $currentdate) {
echo 'oldest dates';
} else {
echo 'newest dates';
}
```

Comment: Compare the timestamps instead: `if (strtotime($date) < strtotime($currentdate))` or use DateTime objects instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtotime` function:

```
$date  = strtotime($date);
$currentdate = strtotime($currentdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime($date)<strtotime($currentdate)` 
and make sure that both dates are in correct format.